# Privilege to recover trashed posts

Tags: users, capabilities, customization

I can't seem to find which [built in privilege](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) is required for recovering a trashed post. Would it be `delete_posts`, which is as its name suggests, can move items into the trash and remove them completely, or `edit_posts` or `publish_posts`..?

I aim to have something like, when an admin trashes a post of a lesser role, that lesser role should not be able to recover it. I don't want to add a new capability.

Comment: There are no “lesser” roles. Roles are **not hierarchical** in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capability is `delete_post`, you can [see it in source here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/edit.php#L97).